# Issue with Merging dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've read through the pandas documentation on merging but am still quite confused on how to apply them to my case. I have 2 dataframes that I'd like to merge - I'd like to merge on the common column 'Town', and also merge on the 'values' in a column which are the 'column names' in the 2nd df.

The first df summarizes the top 5 most common venues in each town:

[image: df1]

The second df summarizes the frequencies of all the venue categories in each town:

[image: df2]

The output I want:

Ang Mo Kio | Food Court | Coffee Shop | Dessert Shop | Chinese Restaurant | Japanese Restaurant | Freq of Food Court | Freq of Coffee Shop |...

What I've tried with merge:

```
newdf = pd.merge(sg_onehot_grouped, sg_venues_sorted, left_on=['Town'], right_on=['1st Most Common Venue'])

#only trying the 1st column because wanted to scale down my code
```

but I got an empty dataframe with the column names as all the columns from both dataframes.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Is column '1st Most Common Venue' available  in second df `sg_venues_sorted`

Comment: @NarendraPrasath no it's not